# Eclipse/MySQL: Only one row of data is inserted into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am trying to insert rows of data into MySql, however, when inserting, MySQL is only taking the last row of the data when it should return more than that. Here is my full code for java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException{
    FileReader readFile = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    String timeStamp = null;
    String visitorID = null;;
    String visitorName = null;
    String emailAdd;
    String encryptedEmail = null;
    String countryCode = null;
    String countryName = null;
    String region;
    String timeStampConvo = null;
    String convo = null;
    String nameOfConvo = null;
    String visitorConvo = null;
    String staffConvo = null;
    String staffName = null;



    /////////////////////////////// MYSQL //////////////////////////////////////////    
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webchat_fypj?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "mavis";


    try {
        /////////////////////// READ FROM THE TEXTFILE ////////////////////////////
        String Path = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        readFile = new FileReader(Path+"/src/data/2017-01-16tiff1.text");
        br = new BufferedReader(readFile);
        String str;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Email: "+"([\\w\\-]([\\-\\.\\w])+[\\w\\-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4})");      
        Pattern timing = Pattern.compile("(" + "(\\d{4})" + "-" + "(\\d{2})" + "-" + "(\\d{2})" + " " + "(\\d{2})"+ ":" + "(\\d{2})" + ":" + "(\\d{2})" + ")");


        ////////////////////// GET CONNECTION TO DATABASE /////////////////////////
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement myStat = (Statement) myConn.createStatement();        
        ///////////////////// GET VALUES FROM TEXTFILE////////////////////////////
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {


            if(str.toLowerCase().contains("timestamp"))
            {
                timeStamp = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "Timestamp: ");
                System.out.println("\n" + "\n" + "Timestamp - " + timeStamp);
            }
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains("visitor id"))
            {
                visitorID = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "Visitor ID: ");
                System.out.println("Visitor ID - " + visitorID);
            }
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains("visitor name"))
            {
                visitorName = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "Visitor Name: ");
                //System.out.println("Visitor Name - " + visitorName);
            }

            /////////////////////////// FOR EMAIL /////////////////////////
            Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
            if(m.find())
            {
                emailAdd = m.group(1);
                try 
                {
                    byte[] enEmail = emailAdd.getBytes();

                    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                    SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

                    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
                    byte encryptEmail[] = c.doFinal(enEmail);

                    encryptedEmail = new String(encryptEmail);
                    if(str.toLowerCase().contains("Visitor Email"))
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Email - " + encryptedEmail.replace("'", "\\'"));
                    }
                    else {
                    //  System.out.println("Email - blank");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            }
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains("country code"))
            {
                countryCode = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "Country Code: ");
                System.out.println("Country Code - " + countryCode);
            }
            if(str.toLowerCase().contains("country name"))
            {
                countryName = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, "Country Name: ");
                System.out.println("Country Name - " + countryName);
            }


            Matcher timematch = timing.matcher(str);
            if(timematch.find())
            {
                timeStampConvo = timematch.group(1);
                //System.out.println("Mini Timestamp - " + timeStampConvo);

                convo = StringUtils.substringAfter(str, timeStampConvo + ") ");
                //System.out.println("convo - " + convo);
                nameOfConvo = StringUtils.substringBefore(convo, ":");
                //System.out.println(nameOfConvo + " ");


                ///////////////////////DATABASE FOR CONVERSATION/////////////////////////////////////////////////
                if(!(nameOfConvo.equals(visitorName))){
                    staffConvo = StringUtils.substringAfter(convo, ": ");
                //  System.out.println("Staff - " + staffConvo);
                    staffName = StringUtils.substringBefore(convo, ": ");
                //  System.out.println("Staff - " + staffName);
                    String staffSql = "INSERT INTO conversation" + "(speaker,convoTimestamp,convo)" + "VALUES ('"+ staffName+"','"+timeStampConvo+"','"+ staffConvo.replace("'", "\\'")+"')";
                    myStat.executeUpdate(staffSql);
                } 
                    else {
                        visitorConvo = StringUtils.substringAfter(convo, ": ");
                    //  System.out.println("Visitor - " + visitorConvo);
                        String visitorSql = "INSERT INTO conversation" + "(speaker,convoTimestamp,convo)" + "VALUES ('"+ visitorName+"','"+timeStampConvo+"','"+ visitorConvo.replace("'", "\\'")+"')";
                        myStat.executeUpdate(visitorSql);
                }

                }

        }
            ///////////////////////////// DATABASE /////////////////////////////////////////            
        String countryCodeSql = "INSERT INTO session" + "(sessionTimestamp,countryCode,countryName,visitorID)" + "VALUES ('"+ timeStamp+"','"+countryCode+"','"+ countryName+"','" + visitorID+"')";
        myStat.executeUpdate(countryCodeSql);

            if (visitorID != null && encryptedEmail !=null){
            String visitorSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO visitor" + "(visitorID,visitorName,visitorEmail)" + "VALUES ('" + visitorID+"','" + visitorName+ "','" + encryptedEmail.replace("'", "\\'")+"')";
            myStat.executeUpdate(visitorSql);
            }




    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    finally {

        try {
            readFile.close();
            br.close();
        }

        catch (IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

}

So this is the main area that i'm facing area with, as the rest of the "INSERT INTO" worked well.

```
    String countryCodeSql = "INSERT INTO session" + "(sessionTimestamp,countryCode,countryName,visitorID)" + "VALUES ('"+ timeStamp+"','"+countryCode+"','"+ countryName+"','" + visitorID+"')";
        myStat.executeUpdate(countryCodeSql);
```

Only one row of data was inserted into MySQL when there should be tons of rows inserted in. Here is MySQL table structure for the table 'session'

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type       | Null    | Key | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sessionID       | int(11)    | NOT NULL| PRI | auto_increment |
| sessionTimestamp| varchar(45)| NULL    |     |                | 
| countryCode     | varchar(45)| NULL    |     |                | 
| countryName     | varchar(45)| NULL    |     |                | 
| visitorID       | varchar(45)| NULL    |     |                | 
| agentID         | varchar(45)| NULL    |     |                |
```

This is the console output in java,

Timestamp - 2017-01-16T00:44:30Z ,
Visitor ID - 1884727.eag9QhwzqaNsAG ,
Country Code - SG ,
Country Name - Singapore ,

Comment: You are executing your query after the `while` loop, that's why it runs only once .

Comment: Oh gosh, you're right! Thank you!